# Examples of three integer sequences defined via indirect recursion (ie. in terms of each other)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm aware of the [Hofstadter Male and Female sequences](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HofstadterMale-FemaleSequences.html), which are a pair of integer sequences defined via mutual recursion:

$$
M(0) = 0
$$
$$
F(0) = 1
$$

$$
M(n) = n - M(F(n-1))
$$
$$
F(n) = n - F(M(n-1))
$$

Are there any known examples of three or more integer sequences defined in similar mannner (via indirect recursion)?